# SugarCRM: Undefined offset: 1

Tags: php, api, laravel-4, sugarcrm

i have this sugar example code from: https://github.com/asakusuma/SugarCRM-REST-API-Wrapper-Class

```
    $sugar = new \Asakusuma\SugarWrapper\Rest;

    $sugar->setUrl('https://sugarcrm/service/v2/rest.php');
    $sugar->setUsername('*******@gmail.com');
    $sugar->setPassword('*****');

    $sugar->connect();

    $error = $sugar->get_error();
    if($error !== FALSE) {
        return $error['name'];
    }
    $results = $sugar->get_with_related("Accounts", array("Accounts" => array('id','name'), "Cases" => array('id','status')));
    $sugar->print_results($results);
```

the error is Undefined offset: 1

i integrated it with laravel 4.2

Comment: i have the same problem. up for this

Answer (score 0):

```
do this

$sugar->setUrl('http://127.0.0.1/mycrm/service/v4_1/rest.php');
$sugar->setUsername('foo');
$sugar->setPassword('bar');
$sugar->connect();

i assume your setUrl is the address where you crm resides.

$results = $sugar->get_with_related("Accounts", array("Accounts" => array('id','name'), "Cases" => array('id','status')));
    $sugar->print_results($results);
```